# PyInstaller 2.0 TypeError: compile() expected string without bull bytes

Tags: python-2.7, typeerror, pyinstaller

Background:

- Mac OSX 10.7.5
- Python 2.7.3
- PyInstaller 2.0

I am trying to make a simple script into a single executable using PyInstaller.  However, every time I try running `pyinstaller.py`(after navigating to the pyinstaller folder of course) I get an error:

```
TypeError: compile() expected string without null bytes
```

Here is the [full console output](http://pastebin.com/R1RDPMB8) and the [script itself](http://pastebin.com/t4t7MjqQ). Anyone know what is going wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I got the same error. I have just found this link (http://www.gossamer-threads.com/lists/python/python/821709) and your doubt here about this error.

I have tried to install cx_freeze (https://pypi.python.org/pypi/cx_Freeze/4.3.1) but I got the error:

```
pip install cx_freeze

error: option --single-version-externally-managed not recognized
```

I do not know if one lib uses the other..